# Set default value in while loop using Php Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to mysqli Object oriented style and I'm trying to put a default value if their is no data from the database for that category.

This is what I've got so far

[image] 'R8 0 1.0' should be in R8 Column

My code:

```
<tr>
<td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $inv; ?></td>
<?php
    $stmtProd = $db -> prepare("SELECT riou.rIOu_Pr_code, riou.rIOu_boughtCase, riou.rIOu_boughtBottle FROM retail_items_ou riou INNER JOIN products pr ON (riou.rIOu_Pr_id = pr.Pr_id) INNER JOIN products_extent pe ON (riou.rIOu_Pr_id = pe.pE_Pr_id) WHERE riou.rIOu_rInOu_id = ? AND pr.Pr_category = '8 oz' ORDER BY pe.pE_individualArrange");
    $stmtProd -> bind_param('i',$id);
    $stmtProd -> execute();
    $stmtProd -> bind_result($code,$case,$bot);
    while($test = $stmtProd -> fetch()){
        if($test === null){
            echo '<td>Default Value</td>';
        }else{
            echo '<td>'.$code.' '.$case.'.'.$bot.'</td>';
        }
    }
    $x++;
?>
</tr>
```

Output should be like this:
[image]

The if statment is not working. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply run a check to see if (for example) code equals to 0 (which I presume it does if SQL returns an empty field). If it does, set the variable to something different.

```
$code = ($code == 0) ? "Default value" : $code;
```

Do this for each item you wish to double-check has a value. If you dislike ternary's, you could of course just do it with a standard if case.

```
if(!$code)
{
    $code = "Default value";
}
```

Comment: not working. It seem if the category is empty, it doesn't run the code inside the while loop and skips to the next category.

Comment: If you run that query on an empty category in SQL through for example phpmyadmin, what does it respond? Surely it would return something?

Comment: 'R8 0 1.0' is only the output in phpmyadmin

Comment: Would that accurately fall under the $code variable, or would it go into the $case or $bot? Unsure of what is linked to where here.